# To detect if LiveConnect is blocked

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'd like to know if it is possible to detect and display an alert if LiveConnect is blocked due to expired JRE and High+ security settings? Currently I can see this message in the Java Console:

```
"security: LiveConnect (JavaScript) blocked due to security settings."
```

I would like to display a message on the browser either on the web page (if it is web page -> applet communication) or from the applet (if it is applet -> web page communication).

For us, a message to let the user know a Java update is required for the applet to fully function would be more useful than a security warning in the Java Console.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that a `try`/`catch` in the applet itself is the best approach to this.

Or in other words, try some minor action at start-up.  If it reaches the catch, pop a message up for the user.